# .htaccess - RewriteCond to exclude a path not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all paths to the domain https://www.test.com except url where path starting with /tutorial or is an image. For example:

https://www.test.com/testing => https://www.test.com
https://www.test.com/tutorial/xx => https://www.test.com/tutorial/xx

I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(test\.(?:com))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tutorial/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|svg|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz|map)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://www.test.com [R=301,L]
```

But this code is not working. Even I put https://www.test.com/tutorial/xx always redirect to the https://www.test.com. I also tested in htaccess tester(https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/) and it looks the RewriteCond should be OK. But obviously is not.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this redirection using an .htaccess file in an Apache web server environment, you can create or modify your .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tutorial/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. Yes I adjusted the htaccess but now Im getting this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.